# What is "java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1 "?

Tags: java, mysql

I don't know what is wrong with my code below.

```
 try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO  `myporject`.`selectnation` (`nations` ,`package` ,`persons`) "
                + "VALUES ('?',  ?,  ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
        if (ps.executeUpdate() != -1) {
            ps.setString(1,"Japan" );
            ps.setInt(2, this.pack);
            ps.setString(3, jTextField1.getText());
```

And this is StackTrace

> java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: Uh... maybe set the parameters before executing the query?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to execute the `prepareStatement` before setting the parameters, so you need to change your code as follows:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

//set the parameters first
ps.setString(1,"Japan" );
ps.setInt(2, this.pack);
ps.setString(3, jTextField1.getText());

//now execute the prepared statement
if (ps.executeUpdate() != -1) {
  //add your code
}
```

I suggest you refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to understand the jdbc concepts.